# Row level operation in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Below is sample table.

INPUT

```
id  col1    start     End          totaltime 
1   1       9:13:22   9:43:11      00:30:11
2    0.5    9:23:22   9:43:11      00:19:49
1    1      9:45:20   10:45:11    ......
2   0.5     10:50:44 11:30:01    ......
```

Here "start" column is sorted one. 
I need to compare start of current row to end of previous row. If the condition is 
satisfied then the value in th column "col1" need to be added for both rows.

something like this.

```
col1 
1.5
```

Is this row level operation possible in Pig, In SQL row level calculations are  possible with self join, LAG and LEAD functions.
what are the options in Pig, or else need to write UDF for this? This is a sample data, actual data is around 40 million rows.

Please suggest.

Comment: Not tested, but [PiggyBank](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/PIG/PiggyBank) seems to [have something](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/evaluation/Over.html)

Comment: As for as i know that,there is no row level operation in Pig. But you can try it with using UDF's.

Comment: Can anybody give me some pointers on constructing UDF for above case? input will be csv file containing above mentioned "input" data.